# Why is my wxPython program not working? (Code inside)

Tags: python, wxpython

So I have to write a BMI calculator. I cannot get it to work tho.

Before I added the class and the methods it was working fine but in order to make the Compute button working I had to use a class. And once I did it broke.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import wx


class BMI(wx.Frame):

def InitUI(self):
    window = wx.Frame(self, title="wx.SpinCtrl", size=(400, 300))
    panel = wx.Panel(window)
    label = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Body Mass Index", pos=(20, 10))
    self.weight = wx.StaticText(panel, label="weight:", pos=(20, 70))
    self.height = wx.StaticText(panel, label="height:", pos=(20, 140))
    weightset = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value='0', pos=(100, 70))
    heightset = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value='0', pos=(100, 140))
    result = wx.StaticText(panel, label="BMI:", pos=(300, 110))
    result2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label=" ", pos=(335, 110))
    computeButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Compute', pos=(40, 200))
    closeButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Close', pos=(250, 200))
    computeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ComBMI)
    closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

def ComBMI(self, e):
    teglo = self.weight.GetValue()
    vis = self.height.GetValue()
    bmi = teglo * (pow(vis, 2))
    self.result2.SetLabel(str(bmi))

def OnClose(self, e):
    self.Close(True)


def main():

 app = wx.App()
 ex = BMI(None)
 ex.Show()
 app.MainLoop()


 if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resolve the `__init__` of your class.
Use the spinctrl values not the text objects.
Define the weight to be a float or explain the value to be input is in Centimetres.
The formula is weight(Kgs) / (height (M) * height) unless you want to set off a plethora of un-necessary crash diets ;)
You may want to add the ability to choose between Metric and Imperial values

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.floatspin as FS

class BMI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='BMI Calculatot')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        label = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Body Mass Index", pos=(20, 10))
        weightT = wx.StaticText(panel, label="weight (Kgs):", pos=(20, 70))
        heightT = wx.StaticText(panel, label="height (M):", pos=(20, 140))
        self.weight = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value='0', min=0, max=500, pos=(100, 70))
        #self.height = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value='0', min=100, max=250, pos=(100, 140))

        self.height = FS.FloatSpin(panel, -1, min_val=1.00, max_val=2.50, increment=0.01, pos=(100, 140))
        self.height.SetFormat("%f")
        self.height.SetDigits(2)

        resultT = wx.StaticText(panel, label="BMI:", pos=(300, 110))
        self.result = wx.StaticText(panel, label=" ", pos=(335, 110))
        computeButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Compute', pos=(40, 200))
        closeButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Close', pos=(250, 200))
        computeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ComBMI)
        closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

    def ComBMI(self, e):
        teglo = self.weight.GetValue()
        vis = self.height.GetValue()
        bmi = teglo / (pow(vis, 2))
        self.result.SetLabel(str(round(bmi,3)))

    def OnClose(self, e):
        self.Close(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    ex = BMI()
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't quite get the `__init__` part. Can you recommend me some read about it?

Comment: Upvote the answer from @nepix32 because they have given you the link to a wx.Frame tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Uhh, question is why is any of this even working...

Issues (probably incomplete):

1. No proper initializsation of class `BMI` (see [a tutorial](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/firststeps/) how to use a `wx.Frame` class properly)
2. Use of `SpinCtrl` will either not allow entering height in meter or limit people to 100 cm in heigth (and 100 kg in weight, by the way). Use as `TextCtrl` instead and parse the value with `float` (or modify the range/resolution of the `SpinCtrl`)
3. You do a `self.weigth.GetValue()` on a object attribute, but user input goes to `self.weightset`
4. Wrong BMI formula (look it up on wiki), linked to that wrong units